Working with JSON data, dynamic headers and value
How to deal with json data that has different value and headers. The json data changes every time, and it's hard to keep on updating my query.
is there any way to write it and adapt to any new header/value comes in?
The query that I have is written like this:
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    jd.job_id,
    jd.id AS id,
    jd.unit_id,
    jd.worker_id,
    jd.started_at,
    jd.updated_at,
    json_extract_path_text(jd.data, 'q1') AS q1,
    json_extract_path_text(jd.data, 'q2') AS q2,
    json_extract_path_text(jd.data, 'q3') AS q3,
    json_extract_path_text(jd.data, 'q4') AS q4
FROM 
data jd


If you want the query to be dynamically (re)constructed based on the json structure, use dynamic SQL. If the json keeps changing but you always want only the values under the initial 4 keys, you can pass the results from json_object_keys() into your json_extract_path_text(): json_extract_path_text(jd.data, k_arr[4]) AS q4 FROM data jd CROSS JOIN LATERAL (select array_agg(k) as k_arr from json_object_keys(jd.data)k )_
